# Prayer Time Alarm

Tags: flutter, dart, alarmmanager, background-service, flutter-packages

Prayer Time Alarm: Is there any way to awaken my app in background when the Current time is equal to Prayer Time. background_fetch package is there but it awaken app after every 15 minute interval. Can you guide for how much period the package awake our app?

Comment: Hey, I have a question for you. How are you selecting the calculation method for prayer? because almost every country uses different calculation methods. BTW, I am also working on a prayer time app.

Comment: This question needs some attention, I hope some one answer it.